# query images in a tableviewcell that is saved in Parse

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8

I tried to query  images saved in my database through my UITableviewCell ,so at i created the Tableview file and a UITableviewcell file

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayM objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7ca8db30'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line...

```
_arrayimages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:objects,nil];
```

...will always create a single element array whose first element is the array of results.  The datasource gets the element at index 0 and, thinking its a PFObject, sends `objectForKey:` to it... crash.

The fix is simple and more concise...

```
self.arrayimages = objects;
```

Comment: it works man  and do you know how when you tap on the image in the tableviewcell for it to appear in a UIviewcontroller

Comment: Its a new question, but the short answer is to use a navigation controller, when didSelectRowAtIndexPath, have your navigation controller do a push to a detail view controller.